# fast 2dimensional histograming in matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, histogram

I have written a 2D histogram algorithm for 2 matlab vectors.  Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to vectorize it, and it is about an order of magnitude too slow for my needs.  Here is what I have:

```
    function [ result ] = Hist2D( vec0, vec1 )
%Hist2D takes two vectors, and computes the two dimensional histogram
% of those images.  It assumes vectors are non-negative, and bins
% are the integers.
%
%  OUTPUTS
%      result - 
%         size(result) = 1 + [max(vec0) max(vec1)]
%         result(i,j)  = number of pixels that have value 
%                             i-1 in vec0 and value j-1 in vec1.

    result = zeros(max(vec0)+1, max(vec1)+1);

    fvec0 = floor(vec1)+1;
    fvec1 = floor(vec0)+1;

    % UGH, This is gross, there has to be a better way...
    for i = 1 : size(fvec0);
        result(fvec0(i), fvec1(i)) = 1 + result(fvec0(i), fvec1(i));
    end
end
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!!
John

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is my version for a 2D histogram:

```
%# some random data
X = randn(2500,1);
Y = randn(2500,1)*2;

%# bin centers (integers)
xbins = floor(min(X)):1:ceil(max(X));
ybins = floor(min(Y)):1:ceil(max(Y));
xNumBins = numel(xbins); yNumBins = numel(ybins);

%# map X/Y values to bin indices
Xi = round( interp1(xbins, 1:xNumBins, X, 'linear', 'extrap') );
Yi = round( interp1(ybins, 1:yNumBins, Y, 'linear', 'extrap') );

%# limit indices to the range [1,numBins]
Xi = max( min(Xi,xNumBins), 1);
Yi = max( min(Yi,yNumBins), 1);

%# count number of elements in each bin
H = accumarray([Yi(:) Xi(:)], 1, [yNumBins xNumBins]);

%# plot 2D histogram
imagesc(xbins, ybins, H), axis on %# axis image
colormap hot; colorbar
hold on, plot(X, Y, 'b.', 'MarkerSize',1), hold off
```

[image: hist2d]

Note that I removed the "non-negative" restriction, but kept integer bin centers (this could be easily changed into dividing range into equally-sized specified number of bins instead "fractions").

This was mainly inspired by @SteveEddins [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/12/23/two-dimensional-histograms/).

Comment: accumarray, why did I not know about this function?  Awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: accumarray is about 30x faster than my approach when run on my machine.

Comment: @John: you can read more about the under-appreciated ACCUMARRAY here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/

Comment: Pretty nice, but why use linear interpolation?  You can use 'nearest' interpolation and skip the rounding and limit range steps.

Comment: @Chinasaur: I think you are right `Xi =  interp1(xbins, 1:xNumBins, X, 'nearest', 'extrap');` is simpler (similar for `Y`). Since this was some time ago, I can't guarantee there are no corner cases though :)

Comment: The histogram above is expressed in terms of *bin centers*. If we had formulated the binning in terms of *bin edges* instead, we could use HISTC function as well (in which case the ranges don't even have to be of equal size)..

Comment: AMro - but how to feed different size ranges to `accumarray` ?  Have to zero-pad the shorter of the two ranges, or something, since the first argument to `accumarray` has to have columns of equal length, right?

Comment: Never mind -- I was not paying attention.   `[xct,xedge,xbin]=histcounts(x)` , then  `accumarray([xbin',ybin'],1,[numel(xedge),numel(yedge)])` basically works, aside from scaling values into bin count.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: right, `histcounts` is the modern replacement of `histc` I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
max0 = max(fvec0) + 1;
max1 = max(fvec1) + 1;

% Combine the vectors
combined = fvec0 + fvec1 * max0;

% Generate a 1D histogram
hist_1d = hist(combined, max0*max1);

% Convert back to a 2D histogram
hist_2d = reshape(hist, [max0 max1]);
```

(Note: untested)