# 2D histogram using data from large text file- matlab

Tags: matlab

What I need to do is write code that will compute the min, max, mean, and std of numerical data found in a very large text file and I've done that. BUT, I also need to plot 2D histograms of the data and this is where I'm having trouble. The data contains no negative numbers (although at some point I will need to know how to handle that one!) and contains NaNs, and the histogram will need to use 1000s of bins to smooth out the 49,000 values in the array. So, x-axis is bins, y-axis is the number distribution of the values in the array.
Here's what I have:

```
 N = 100; %I'm using blocks because it's so much data
solarmax = fopen('ACE_magswe_64sec_2000.txt','r+');
formatSpec = '%*d %*d %*d %*d %*f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f';

minNp = []; %These are to store the data
maxNp = [];
meanNp = [];
stdNp = [];

minTp = [];     %Above(formatSpec) I'm ignoring the first few columns I don't need 
maxTp = [];  %Below(HeaderL) I'm ignoring the first 2 rows of string data I don't need
meanTp = [];
stdTp = [];


while ~feof(solarmax)
    C = textscan(solarmax,formatSpec,N,'HeaderLines',2,'Delimiter','\t'); 
    Np = cell2mat(C(:,1)); %Calling the columns of data I need
    Tp = cell2mat(C(:,2));

    Np(Np == -9999.90039) = NaN; %Replacing default error values chosen by satellite
    Tp(Tp == -9999.90039) = NaN;

    minNp(end+1) = min(Np);
    maxNp(end+1) = max(Np);
    meanNp(end+1) = mean(Np);
    stdNp(end+1) = std(Np);

    minTp(end+1) = min(Tp);
    maxTp(end+1) = max(Tp);
    meanTp(end+1) = mean(Tp);
    stdTp(end+1) = std(Tp);

end
fclose(solarmax);

nanmin(minNp);      %nan command ignores NaNs in computation
nanmax(maxNp);      %not sure why it didn't do that anyway but whatever
nanmean(meanNp);
nanstd(stdNp);
nanmin(minTp);      %These are here to compute the same operation on the 
nanmax(maxTp);      %blocks of data & so I can check that it's working properly
nanmean(meanTp);
nanstd(stdTp);
```

So, I tried including the hist command in the while loop the same way I did the other functions but it's just a different animal and trust me I've looked and I found lots of info on histograms but nothing like my situation. Do I include it in the while loop at all? The data is defined but it's reading and storage has to be different... please help me... thank you for your time

UPDATE

I decided to just try to plot the histogram separately without the other mess for now.

```
 N = 150;
solarmax = fopen('ACE_magswe_64sec_2000.txt','r+');
formatSpec = '%*d %*d %*d %*d %*f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f';

histcNp = []; %I need somewhere to store the data in the blocks but I'm wondering
histcTp = []; %if it already does that in bincounts

while ~feof(solarmax)
    C = textscan(solarmax,formatSpec,N,'HeaderLines',2,'Delimiter','\t');
    Np = cell2mat(C(:,1)); %my data should be defined here
    Tp = cell2mat(C(:,2));

    Np(Np == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Tp(Tp == -9999.90039) = NaN;

    binranges = 0:150;

    %NpH = histcNp(end+1); %as you can see I've tried stuff and then commented
    %TpH = histcTp(end+1); %it so I can go back

    %histcNp = (Np,0:150);
    %histcTp = (Tp,0:150);



 end
fclose(solarmax);

%bar(Np,0:494110,'histc');
%bar(NpH,Name,density);
%bar(Tp,0:494110,'histc');
bar(0:150,Np,'histc');
[bincounts] = histc(Np,binranges);
```

And just so I don't seem too scrambled. My direct question is do I define my number of bins outside the loop? Thank you for your time.

Comment: DId you try `hist`? Just type `help hist` in your command window for further information. THere you can Get all the informations you need. As far as i know `hist(y_data, NoOfBins)`would be the code you need. Where `y_data` is obviously your data and `NoOFBins` would be `1000`(you said so in your first paragraph). It should even work with negative numbers but not sure about that.

Comment: Otherwise `hist3()` could be also interesting.

Comment: you should first define the "bins" you want, then use `histc` over each block. This will give you the counts within each specified bin. Finally you simply accumulate the counts from all data blocks. To plot a histogram, use the `bar` function giving it the counts and the bin edges/centers. (btw this is not called a 2D histogram, just a regular 1D histogram)

Comment: @Amro are you sure about it beeing a 1d-hist? Because as far as i see he uses `Np` and `Tp` (Both dimension(N,1)). And even if so wouldn't `hist`or `hist3` do just the trick?

Comment: @TheMinion: from his description: "x-axis is bins, y-axis is the number distribution of the values", so I think `Np` and `Tp` are just to be treated as two separate arrays, meaning two separate 1D histograms. At least that's what I understood.. For what it's worth, here is an example computing a 2D histogram using core MATLAB functions (no toolboxes): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778256/97160

Comment: You're right about it being just a 1D histogram (for now) and histc seems to be the way for me to go but do I define the number of bins outside the loop and then include my histc function inside the loop? I can't seem to find anything on inputting an array from a large data file to plot a histogram. If you have any more advice, I'd appreciate it but I understand if not. The closest I got was bins of just zeroes which makes me think the data is not being read correctly. I'll include some code above to show you what I've tried.