# Sorting 2D coordinates into bins in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, grid, 2d, binning

I am trying to sort random coordinates on a 2D cartesian grid using MATLAB into "bins" defined by a grid.

For example if I have a 2D domain with X ranging from [-1,1] and Y from [-1,1] and I generate some random coordinates within the domain, how can I "count" how many coordinates fall into each quadrant?

I realize that for and if statements can be used to determine the if each coordinate is within the quadrants, but I would like to scale this to much larger square grids that have more than just 4 quadrants.

Any concise and efficient approach would be appreciated!

Comment: try this 2d histogram code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778256/97160

Comment: Why not just use built-in `hist3`?

Comment: @LuisMendo: unlike [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) doesn't return the bin indices where each point was assigned, it only computes the 2D histogram (counts in each bin). Think of `hist3` as the 2-D version of [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function. Note that `hist3` requires Statistics toolbox... FYI there is a [`histcn`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23897) submission on File Exchange that uses the same technique I've shown to extend it to N-dimensions

Comment: @Amro Thanks for your answer. I thought the OP only wanted to count how many values are in each bin, as opposed to knowing the bin for each value. Anyway your answer is great, you already had my +1 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example adapted from [the code I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778256/97160).

The resulting binned points are be stored the variable `subs`; Each row contains 2d subscript indices of the bin to which a point was assigned.

```
% 2D points, both coordinates in the range [-1,1]
XY = rand(1000,2)*2 - 1;

% define equal-sized bins that divide the [-1,1] grid into 10x10 quadrants
mn = [-1 -1]; mx = [1 1];  % mn = min(XY); mx = max(XY);
N = 10;
edges = linspace(mn(1), mx(1), N+1);

% map points to bins
% We fix HISTC handling of last edge, so the intervals become:
% [-1, -0.8), [-0.8, -0.6), ..., [0.6, 0.8), [0.8, 1]
% (note the last interval is closed on the right side)
[~,subs] = histc(XY, edges, 1); 
subs(subs==N+1) = N;

% 2D histogram of bins count
H = accumarray(subs, 1, [N N]);

% plot histogram
imagesc(H.'); axis image xy
set(gca, 'TickDir','out')
colormap gray; colorbar
xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y')

% show bin intervals
ticks = (0:N)+0.5;
labels = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(edges(:),'%g')));
set(gca, 'XTick',ticks, 'XTickLabel',labels, ...
    'YTick',ticks, 'YTickLabel',labels)

% plot 2D points on top, correctly scaled from [-1,1] to [0,N]+0.5
XY2 = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, XY, mn), mx-mn) * N + 0.5;
line(XY2(:,1), XY2(:,2), 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'Color','r')
```

[image: 2d_bins]

Comment: Thanks Amro, this and your earlier comment really helped!

Comment: @akshayjd: sorry there was a typo: we should have transposed the matrix `H` when displaying it as an image. I've fixed the code and made some small changes..