# Density of points on XY plane

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap

I have a set of points on the XY plane and I would like to plot the points density (as heatmap or 3d histogram). How do you suggest to do it? Thanks!

Here are the points:

[image]

Comment: Define what sampling you want for the point density. Overlapping blocks or not, size of bin (resolution of the density map), rectangular or circular blocks, etc. I think this little thinking process paves the way for drawing a heatmap. Eg: for non overlapping rectangular blocks, you just need to compute a spatial 2D histogram of your data, and you get your heatmap.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777609/fast-2dimensional-histograming-in-matlab